# JFrame Resizing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, miglayout

I switched to the MigLayout and when I drag the window smaller the components resize, but when I drag it bigger than the size when I start the program, they don't get bigger. How do I make it so it resizes bigger and smaller?

```
public SpriteEditor() {
    SubstanceColorChooserUI col = new SubstanceColorChooserUI();
    while (mode == 0);
    setResizable(true);
    setTitle("DawnGuard Index 32/34 Editor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(483, 374);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnLoadCache = new JButton("Load cache");
    btnLoadCache.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                String loc = textField.getText();
                if (loc.equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SpriteEditor.this, "Please specify a location for the cache.", "Unable to load", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
                if (!loc.endsWith("\\"))
                    loc = loc + "\\";
                cache = new Store(loc);
                loadImages();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SpriteEditor.this, "Cache failed to initialize.\n" + e.getMessage(), "Unable to load", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    splitPane.setDividerLocation(150);
    splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);

    JPanel panellie = new JPanel();
    panellie.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    panel = new ImagePanel(null);

    scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    panellie.add(scrollPane_1, "Center");

    scrollPane_1.setViewportView(panel);
    splitPane.setRightComponent(panellie);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    splitPane.setLeftComponent(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    panel_1.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    model = new DefaultListModel<ListedImage>();
    list = new JList<ListedImage>(model);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getValueIsAdjusting())
                return;
            ListedImage img = list.getModel().getElementAt(list.getSelectedIndex());
            panel.setImage(img.getImage());
        }
    });
    scrollPane.setViewportView(list);

    progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    progressBar.setDoubleBuffered(true);

    contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[328px][13px][112px]", "[23px][279px][14px]"));
    contentPane.add(textField, "cell 0 0,growx,aligny center");
    contentPane.add(btnLoadCache, "cell 2 0,growx,aligny top");
    contentPane.add(splitPane, "cell 0 1 3 1,grow");
    contentPane.add(progressBar, "cell 0 2 3 1,grow");

}
```

Comment: Myself, I advise against trying to hand-code GroupLayout. Much better to use nested JPanels that use simpler layout managers or downloading MigLayout and using that.

Comment: I use windowbuilder for eclipse

Comment: Edit: I just use MigLayout, but it can't resize larger, only smaller.

Comment: Many a Layouts do respect the preferred size of the given Component, though there are certain Layouts, which when used wisely, can give you the desired outcome, such as `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout(in this you can control the size of each component)`/`BorderLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the layout definition you have:

```
contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[328px][13px][112px]", "[23px][279px][14px]"));
```

well you could try telling the layout to fill with layout constraint `fill`, now you should tell wich column(s) and row(s) should grow when the panel grows with the row/column constraint `grow`. So...

```
contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill", "[328px, grow][13px][112px]", "[23px][279px, grow][14px]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the maximum size is too small, you are trying to set a bigger size than the maximum size of the object. Try setting the maximum width and the maximum height. Good luck.

Comment: Just call the setMaximumSize method of your JFrame object. You should pass a Dimension object to it, like this: myFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,550)); where myFrame is your JFrame object.

Comment: Where did you set the maximum size? I don't see that part in your code.